Psql giving permission denied on loading via file
My problem is similar to the one here but the solution doesn't seem to work.
I have a file data.sql at /path/to/file/data.sql.
I connect log in to the shell as postgres user via:
(py39bot) me@pop-os:~/bot/code$ sudo -i -u postgres

postgres@pop-os:~$ psql
psql (14.12 (Ubuntu 14.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

Then I run psql and then use the \i command but this gives Permission denied. :
postgres=# \i /home/sheharyar/bot/code/data.sql
/home/sheharyar/bot/code/data.sql: Permission denied
postgres=# 

Doing chmod 777 data.sql does not help. I presumed it had something to do with rights to the parent folders in the file path but chmod +R didn't work either.
When I'm logged in as postgres user, I can't run cat /path/to/file/data.sql either. So it has something to do with file reading.
Can someone clarify?

"I connect using: sudo -i -u postgres" This does not connect to Postgres, it creates a login shell as the postgres user. Presumably you then run psql? Show us that command, please. You shouldn't have to switch to the postgres user to connect to Postgres.

Yes, you are correct. I've made some edits to make the prompt clearer.

Not surprising the 2nd chmod didn't work. I don't know what it was intended to do, but   "chmod: invalid mode: '+R'"

Afaik, the postgres OS user has only access to the postgres data directory, and no other files. But I don't think the "why" matters, you just shouldn't log in to their shell at all.
Instead, as your regular OS user (which presumably has access to the data.sql file), run psql and pass parameters to connect as the postgres database user:
(py39bot) me@pop-os:~/bot/code$ psql -U postgres


To expand, the postgres user can't access /home/sheharyar/bot/code/data.sql because it (presumably) does not have permission to traverse the /home/sheharyar/ directory (the x permission). Even if it has permission to read the file, it cannot traverse its parent directories to read the file. This is as it should be, other users should not be able to access your home directory.
